# How to prove that the center of a group is not a maximal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> How to prove $Z(G)$ is not a maximal subgroup of $G$?

So I used the fact that $Z(G)$ is a subset of the $C(a)$ which is a subgroup of some group $G$. Is that sufficient? If not can you provide a proof?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** Assume that $Z(G)\ne G$ **(why?)**

Then there exists $a\in G$ such that $a$ is not in $Z(G)$

You know that $Z(G)\le C(a) \le G$

But here, $Z(G)< C(a) < G$ **(why < ?)**

And with this you're done showing $Z(G)$ is not maximal in $G$

Comment: I hope you know the notations $<$ and $\le$. The former is for proper subgroup

Comment: I am lost as to why you assume Z(G) is not G.

Comment: Does it follow that since Z(G) = intersection C(a) for a in G that Z(G)<C(a)<G?

Comment: What is the definition of maximal subgroup?

Comment: A proper subgroup H of a group G is called maiximal if there is no subgroup K such that H<K<G. @Swapnil Tripathi

Comment: For $Z(G)<C(a)$ there is a very obvious element in $C(a)$ that is not in $Z(G)$. What is it? For $C(a)<G$, suppose $C(a)=G$ what can you say about $a$? What contradiction do you reach.

Comment: Yes, since you can talk about maximality only when $H$ (in this case $Z(G)$) is proper. That is, $H\ne G$

Comment: The element a is in C(a) but not in Z(G)?  @Swapnil Tripathi

Comment: Yes. Absolutely right. What about the contradiction when $C(a)=G$?

Comment: I am a little stuck on that part, can you guide me? @Swapnil Tripathi

Comment: If $C(a)=G$. Then, $a$ commutes with all elements of $G$. Contradiction?

Comment: Oh man! I was just about to comment that, I lack conviction. Thanks. One other thing: why do we assume that Z(G)=!G?

Comment: Reread all the comments. You'll find it.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $Z(G)$ is maximal, then $G/Z(G)$ doesn't have any non-trivial subgroup.

This implies that $G/Z(G)$ has a prime order and hence is cyclic.

Now prove that this implies that every two elements of $G$ commute, which leads to $Z(G)=G$, contradiction.

Comment: Why does Z(G) maximal imply G/Z(G) does not have any non-trivial subgroup?

Comment: The subgroup correspondence theorem states that subgroups of $G/N$ correspond to subgroups of $G$ containing $N$, where $N$ is normal in $G$. Thus, if $G/Z(G)$ contains a non-trivial subgroup, then $G$ has a subgroup containing $Z(G)$, so $Z(G)$ is not maximal.

Comment: @WilliamStagner I have never seen that theorem. What other way can I go about it?

Comment: @fr, if you haven't seen the correspondence then google it. It is one of the most basic, important theorem in basic group theory.