# $M$ is normal if $Z\not\subseteq M$

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group. Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. I have to solve the following questions:

(a) Prove that $M$ is normal if the center $Z$ of $G$ satisfies $Z\not\subseteq M$.

(b) Prove $G/M$ is a cyclic group of prime order if $M$ is a maximal normal subgroup of $G$.

I found the proof for (b) [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161592/quotient-group-by-a-maximal-subgroup-is-abelian?lq=1). My goal now is to look for a proof for (a) that does not use (b). I guess the [correspondence theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_%28Group_Theory%29) and the fact that [center is not a maximal subgroup of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023531/how-to-prove-that-the-center-of-a-group-is-not-a-maximal-subgroup) may help to deal with (a). However I haven't gotten the answer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Hint : The normalizer of $M$ contains $M$ and contains $Z$.

Comment: As for your hint, we write $M \le N_G(M) \le G$. Since $M$ is maximal, we have $M=N_G(M)$, for otherwise we're done. How can I go further?

Comment: @user From $M\subseteq N_G(M)$ and $M$ maximal we get that $N_G(M)=M$ or $N_G(M)=G$ (i.e. $M$ normal). Furthermore it is clear that $Z\subseteq N_G(M)$ so if $Z$ is not included in $M$ then $N_G(M)\neq M$.

Comment: It's correct. Thanks a lot @ClémentGuérin.